# Array of enum types conforming to a protocol with an associated type

Tags: swift, protocols, hashtable

Let's consider a simplified case, with two enum types conforming to `CaseIterable`.

```swift
enum A: String, CaseIterable {
    case a1, a2, a3
}

enum B: String, CaseIterable {
    case b1, b2, b3
}
```

What I want to do is create some sort of hash table associating a key (a String in my example) and the **type** of the enums:

```swift
let dict: [String : CaseIterable.Type] = [ // Error here: Protocol 'CaseIterable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
    "my key A" : A.self,
    "my key B" : B.self
]
```

What I need to achieve in the end is to "query" my hash table for a specific key and apply a protocol method on the result (say `allCases`).

```swift
let cases = dict["my key A"]!.allCases
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: And here the associated type the compiler complains about is the enum itself so A and B in your case.

Comment: What (statically, known at compile-time) type do you expect `cases` to be? It's "the cases of some unknown enum," so what would you then do with this variable? You don't know anything about what those cases are or what methods you can call on them. If you show the code of what you would do with `cases`, then that will reveal the actual protocol you mean to use (rather than CaseIterable)

Comment: Assigning the same string value to your cases is pointless

Comment: @Rob Napier: all the enums are known at compile time. Each of the enums describes a different situation so each of them will have different cases. The actual protocol I need to use is ‘CaseIterable’ - I want to display a menu listing all the possible options.

Comment: @Leo Dabus:  is not pointless, is just an example, the string values are irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: One more reason to just omit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to display a menu listing all the possible options.

So you want Strings, not the cases themselves. That's absolutely doable. First, start by saying what you *really* want the type to do in the form of a protocol:

```
protocol CaseNamed {
    static var caseNames: [String]
}
```

If you had that, you could build what you want:

```
var enums: [CaseNamed.Type] = [A.self, B.self]
enums.flatMap { $0.caseNames }
```

(I call this "wish driven development." I wish I had a type that could....)

Now you just need to conform types to CaseNamed by implementing `caseNames`. Luckily that's easy if the type also happens to conform to CaseIterable:

```
extension CaseNamed where Self: CaseIterable {
    static var caseNames: [String] {
        self.allCases.map { "\($0)" }
    }
}
```

But you can have CaseNamed types that don't conform to CaseIterable. CaseIterable isn't a requirement. It's just nice if you have it. Here's the full code:

```
protocol CaseNamed {
    static var caseNames: [String] { get }
}

enum A: String, CaseIterable, CaseNamed {
    case a1, a2, a3
}

enum B: String, CaseIterable, CaseNamed {
    case b1, b2, b3
}

extension CaseNamed where Self: CaseIterable {
    static var caseNames: [String] {
        self.allCases.map { "\($0)" }
    }
}

var enums: [CaseNamed.Type] = [A.self, B.self]

enums.flatMap { $0.caseNames }
```

Now of course you might also want this CaseNamed protocol to do other things, so you can add those other things. But you need to think in terms of the calling code and what it fundamentally needs to do its job.